# How to create username password identity for Azure API Management service using Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

In terraform, it supports various Azure API Management service identities and not username password. how to create username password identity from terrafrom?

Terraform azure registry only has the following identity methods and I need to create username password identity method.

```
azurerm_api_management_identity_provider_aad, 
azurerm_api_management_identity_provider_aadb2c 
azurerm_api_management_identity_provider_facebook 
azurerm_api_management_identity_provider_google 
azurerm_api_management_identity_provider_microsoft 
azurerm_api_management_identity_provider_twitter
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you've tried so far? @needTobeanSRE

Comment: @Jahnavi Im also seeking for the code. terraform azure registry only has the following identity methods and i need to create username password identity method.
`azurerm_api_management_identity_provider_aad`, 
`azurerm_api_management_identity_provider_aadb2c`
`azurerm_api_management_identity_provider_facebook`
`azurerm_api_management_identity_provider_google`
`azurerm_api_management_identity_provider_microsoft`
`azurerm_api_management_identity_provider_twitter`

Comment: There is no specific identity provider for creating username and password. You can use `sign_up` property with `azurerm_api_management` resource as explained in the answer. @needTobeanSRE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no dedicated identity provider for creating username and password identities. It means that the provider `Username,Password` is not valid.

By referring to the [github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/5044) attached, it is possible with adding [`sign_up`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management#argument-reference) from the `azurerm_api_management` argument reference. So, it enables username & password identity by default.

```bash
provider "azurerm"{
  features{}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "caroline"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management" "example" {
  name                = "jaanu-apim"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  publisher_name      = "jahnaviorgani"
  publisher_email     = "jahxxxx@terraform.io"

  sku_name = "Developer_1"
  sign_up {
    enabled = true 
    terms_of_service {
      consent_required = false
      enabled = false
    }
}
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

***Added an identity provider for username & password under APIM in portal as shown:***

[image]